# How can I safely check if a python package is outdated?

Tags: python, pypi

I want to include some kind of self-update mechanism on a python package and I do not want to call pip update before the script is run as it is very slow, I am looking for a smart mechanism.

Every time it is used it could make an HTTP call, probably to PyPi and if it would detect a new version it would output a warning on STDERR.

Obviously, as part of this process I would also want to cache the result of last call, so the library would not check for updates more than once a day, let say.

Does anyone has something like this already implemented? Do you have an example that can be used to cache results from HTTP calls, between different executions, so it would not impose signifiant delays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a library [`outdated`](https://github.com/alexmojaki/outdated) to solve this problem. The quickest way to use it is to insert code like this somewhere at the root of your package:

```
from outdated import warn_if_outdated

warn_if_outdated('my-package-name', '1.2.3')
```

This will output a warning on stderr as requested, cache the HTTP call for 24 hours, and more. Details can be found in the link above.

It's also much faster than `pip list -o` even without caching.

Answer (score 14):

To show the outdated packages you can simply run `pip list -o`, but that doesn't involve any caching by itself.

Although it would be trivial to simply add `pip list -o > outdated.txt` to a cronjob so it automatically updates daily :)

Here's some example code to use `pip` as a library:

```
def get_outdated():
    import pip

    list_command = pip.commands.list.ListCommand()
    options, args = list_command.parse_args([])
    packages = pip.utils.get_installed_distributions()

    return list_command.get_outdated(packages, options)

print(get_outdated())
```

Comment: I do want to implement the version check inside the package itself, so users will know that their version is outdated before starting to raise bugs. Let say that 3/5 issues are dups due to them using old versions.

Comment: In that case you could use pip or pip-tools as a library to fetch everything. As far as I can see there is no readily available package to do this but if you use that in combination with a simple caching system (there are libraries like beaker but that's probably overkill) it should do the trick.

Comment: @sorin: take a look at the example I've added for getting the outdated packages programmatically

Comment: @Wolph this does not work any more with current pip (v9.0.1). Do do have a suggestion how one would do this today?

Comment: @mark: it's seems you're right, try the updated version :)

Comment: @Wolph this is so cool to use pip for this. I tried to use an xmlrpc recipe to query PyPi but it did not work very well. your help is much appreciated. thank you!